# Rewriting Ruby Inject

Tags: ruby, inject, enumerator

Here is a brain bender.

I am trying to rewrite the Ruby Inject method. I have got as far as below.

```
class Array

  def injector(input = nil)

    if input == nil
      num = self.first
    else
      num = input
    end
    self[0..-1].each do |x|
      num = yield(num, x)
    end
    return num
  end
end
```

It is passing some tests, but it is not fully accurate, for example;

```
[1,2,3,4,5].injector(0) {|x,y| x + y} #=> 14
```

As opposed to the expected output 15, is it a rounding error? I cannot seem to figure this one out

> Additional example (above updated [0..-1]):

```
[9,8,7,6,5].injector {|x,y| x * y} #=> 136080
```

Ruby .inject outputs 15120

Comment: You start at index 1.

Comment: `self[0..-1]` should fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starting index is important as it depends on your input.

```
class Array

  def injector(input = nil)
    if input.nil?
      start = 1
      num = self.first
    else
      start = 0
      num = input
    end
    self[start..-1].each do |x|
      num = yield(num, x)
    end

    return num
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `nil` as the default is probably wrong, I should be able to pass nil in as the default memo.

```
class Array
  def injector(memo = (i=1; first))
    (i||0).upto(length-1) { |i| memo = yield memo, self[i] }
    memo
  end
end

[1,2,3,4,5].injector(1) { |sum, n| sum + n }
[1,2,3,4,5].injector(0) { |sum, n| sum + n }
[1,2,3,4,5].injector    { |sum, n| sum + n }

[1,2,3].injector(2) { |product, n| product * n }
[1,2,3].injector(1) { |product, n| product * n }
[1,2,3].injector    { |product, n| product * n }

['b', 'c', 'd'].injector('a') { |str, char| str + char } # => "abcd"
['b', 'c', 'd'].injector      { |str, char| str + char } # => "bcd"

seen = []
[1].injector(nil) { |prev, crnt| seen << prev << crnt }
seen # => [nil, 1]
```

Comment: Cheers Josh! Your ruby kickstart was a big helper for me recently